# How do I view the contents of transport.db file in Postfix without the original transport file?

Tags: linux, postfix

A Postfix server was given to me with a **transport.db** file, but no original **transport** file from which it was derived? How do I determine what the original contents of the transport file were?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `file transport.db` which may indicate some version of a Berkeley DB file; if so, something like `db_dump -p transport.db` (assuming `db4-utils` or such is available) would be one way of recovering the data. Another way would be to use some other interface to the BDB format, e.g. the Perl `DB_File` module or such. If the file is not in BDB format (or uses an older BDB format) adjust the tooling as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm heading into the office right now, but I'll take a look at the solution when I get in.

Comment: That worked, ty!

Comment: Also  `postmap -s /etc/postfix/transport`  I know it looks like I am reading the missing file, but it appends .db automagically.  Verified it works if I delete `/etc/postfix/transport`